# How to use jQuery sticky by React.js instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, scroll, sticky

How i can use this jQuery sticky by React.js instead ?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll < 400) {
    $("#sticky-header").removeClass("sticky");
    $('#back-top').fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    $("#sticky-header").addClass("sticky");
    $('#back-top').fadeIn(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you **really** want and need to do? An animation?

Comment: There are a lot of react sticky library out there, for example [this one](https://github.com/gm0t/react-sticky-el), simply follow the usage guide to install the lib and use it

Comment: @Macabeus No, i want to show sticky element after specific pixels from top.

Comment: @MarkoCen,, mmm ,, it may help, i'll try it, thank's :)